# What would cause router to only auto negotiate higher speed when restarted or cable disconnected/reconnected?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

Basic problem is we can't maintain any speed above 100Mbps for very long. Longest 1 week so far. ISP says it's routers, router manufacturer says it's ISP.

Our setup is 4 mesh AEX5400 routers (Wyze router pro units) that have worked pretty well so far, albeit they're slow to boot up and get settled. Switched to a gig speed fixed 5G wireless ISP that uses a Planet L3 switch for building. One mesh router is configured via MAC address for access to switch. ISP doesn't seem familiar with routers and keeps recommending we switch to Google Nest setup. All our Wyze routers but one (wireless) are wired to each other with Cat5e cabling that's been tested and proven working well.

Rebooting main router or disconnecting/reconnecting ISP connection is only way to temporarily restore gig speed. When working we are able to maintain 900Mbps+ on wired connection. ISP can see from L3 switch that port keeps dropping down to lower 100mbps speed and won't maintain despite them "trying something". Tech came out and moved connection to another port, however all regular ports are full so we're on one of the 4 other ports using some kind of adapter. They say that makes no difference.

I guess my question is, if unplugging/replugging ISP connection restores the higher speed what would cause our router to not attempt some similar auto renegotiation, especially if that restores the higher speed for at least a few days at a time.

Comment: `1000mbps` ... 1000 millibits per second?

Comment: You have specified the wrong units. Please fix

Comment: I'd troubleshoot this one step at a time, starting from the Ethernet connection from the ISP. What exactly does that plug into? Your own Ethernet switch, or a Wyze router? Whichever it is, check to see that it negotiates gigabit (1000BASE-T) and stays on gigabit, never falling back to 100 megabit (100BASE-T). If your Ethernet link from your ISP is falling down to 100Mbit/s, then troubleshoot your cabling problem. When two gigabit-capable Ethernet devices fall back to 100Mbit/s signaling, it's almost always a cabling problem like a split pair or sloppy termination job.

Comment: Speed units corrected in original post. Thanks. Connection from ISP goes 5G wireless to a ISP owned building switch (the L3 switch) then cat5e to our apt and our Wyze router. The tech that came out checked and verified gig speed at all connections after switching ports at the L3 switch. If it is bad cable/terminator would router/switch ever attempt a higher speed or do they somehow just know it’s futile and don’t ever try again until a hard break in connection (ex. unplugging/replugging)?